# write a processed bitmap image to a file

Tags: assembly, bitmap, x86, masm, masm32

I'm working on a project that reads the contents of a BMP file and performs a smooth digital filter on the image. My code below almost does the job. I just don't know where I should store the processed pixels and how I can write the processed image to a file. My code below is commented out so Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
        .586
        .model      flat, stdcall
        option      casemap :none
        include     ..\masm32\include\windows.inc
        include     ..\masm32\include\user32.inc
        include     ..\masm32\include\kernel32.inc
        include     ..\masm32\macros\macros.asm
        include     ..\masm32\include\masm32.inc

        includelib  ..\masm32\lib\user32.lib
        includelib  ..\masm32\lib\kernel32.lib
        includelib  ..\masm32\lib\masm32.lib

        .data
FileName    db  "bitmap2.bmp", 0
filename    db  "bitmap_fil.bmp",0
errMsg      BYTE    "Cannot create file",0dh,0ah,0

hFile       HANDLE  ?
hwFile      HANDLE  ?

hMemory     HANDLE  ?       ;incoming data
pMemory     DWORD   ?

hMemory_o   HANDLE  ?       ;outgoing data
pMemory_o   DWORD   ?

ReadSize    DWORD   ?

bytesWritten    DWORD   ?
firstLine   DWORD   ?
FileSize    DWORD   ?
BDoff       DWORD   ?
BHSize      DWORD   ?
szTemp      byte    16 dup (0)  ;buffer for messages
szPrime     byte    "%08i", 0   ;message format string
szPrimeH    byte    "%08lx",0   ;message hexa format string
signature   DD  0
MEMORYSIZE      equ 65535   ;This is how much memory allocated
                        ; to store the file.
im_offset   dd  ?
im_width    dd  ?
im_height   dd  ?
bits_pix    dd  ?





    .code
;................................
show    MACRO   caption, value      
    print   SADD(caption)
    mov eax, value
    invoke  wsprintf, offset szTemp, offset szPrime, eax    ;converts eax into string
    print   offset szTemp                   ;print string
    print   SADD(13,10) 
    ENDM
;..................................

start:  

    invoke      CreateFile, addr FileName,GENERIC_READ,FILE_SHARE_READ,NULL, OPEN_EXISTING,     FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL
    mov      hFile, eax

;Allocate and lock the memory for incoming file.
    invoke      GlobalAlloc, GMEM_MOVEABLE or GMEM_ZEROINIT, MEMORYSIZE
    mov         hMemory, eax
    invoke      GlobalLock, hMemory
    mov         pMemory, eax

;Allocate and lock the memory for outgoing file.
    invoke      GlobalAlloc, GMEM_MOVEABLE or GMEM_ZEROINIT, MEMORYSIZE
    mov         hMemory_o, eax
    invoke      GlobalLock, hMemory_o
    mov         pMemory_o, eax


;Read file and save image parameters
    invoke      ReadFile, hFile, pMemory, MEMORYSIZE-1, addr ReadSize, NULL
    mov     esi, pMemory

    add     esi, 02     ;get filesize
    mov     edi, [esi]
    mov     FileSize,edi
    invoke      wsprintf, offset szTemp, offset szPrime, edi
    print       offset szTemp
    print       SADD(10,13)

    add         esi, 8      ; jump 8 bytes to get image offset
    mov     edi, [esi]  ; get image offset
    mov         im_offset,edi
    invoke      wsprintf, offset szTemp, offset szPrimeH, edi
    print       offset szTemp
    print       SADD(10,13)

    add     esi,8       ;jump 8 bytes to get image width
    mov     edi, [esi]  ; get image width       
    mov     im_width, edi   
    invoke      wsprintf, offset szTemp, offset szPrime, edi
    print       offset szTemp
    print       SADD(10,13)

    add     esi,4       ;jump 4 bytes to get image height
    mov     edi, [esi]  ; get image height
    mov     im_height, edi  
    invoke      wsprintf, offset szTemp, offset szPrime, edi
    print       offset szTemp
    print       SADD(10,13)

    add     esi,4       ;jump 4 bytes to get color plane
    mov     ebx, [esi]  
    shr     ebx,16      ; get color plane and bit-pix
    mov     bits_pix,ebx ;
    print       SADD("bit-per-pix ")
    invoke      wsprintf, offset szTemp, offset szPrime, ebx
    print       offset szTemp
    print       SADD(10,13)

    mov     ebp, pMemory    ; get ready to start processing the image
    add     ebp, im_offset  ; esi now points to the first pix

;filtering process
;leave first row and first column and last row and last column untouched.

    mov     esi,1       ; esi is the row counter
    mov     edi,1       ; edi is the column counter


proc_pix:
    ;show       "current column is: ",edi
    ;show       "current row is: ",esi
    xor     ebx,ebx     ; ebx = 0 ebx will accumulate intermediate values for averaging
    mov     eax, im_width   ; eax is the pointer to the pixel
    mul     esi
    add     eax,edi     
    add     ebx, [ebp+eax]  ;get the pixel(I,J) 

    mov     eax, im_width
    add     esi,1       ;next row (I+1)
    mul     esi
    add     eax,edi     
    add     ebx, [ebp+eax]  ;get the pixel(I+1,J) 


    mov     eax, im_width
    sub     esi,2       ; prev row (I-1)
    mul     esi
    add     eax,edi     
    add     ebx, [ebp+eax]  ;get the pixel(I-1,J) 

    add     esi,1       ;back to the current row

    add     edi,1       ;get next column (J+1)
    mov     eax, im_width
    mul     esi
    add     eax,edi     
    add     ebx, [ebp+eax]  ;get the pixel(I,J+1) 


    sub     edi,2       ; get prev column (J-1)
    mov     eax, im_width
    mul     esi
    add     eax,edi     
    add     ebx, [ebp+eax]  ;get the pixel(I,J-1) 

    add     edi,1       ;back current column
    xor     edx, edx    ;clear upper part dividend
    mov     eax, ebx    ; move data to eax to divide
    mov     ecx, 5  
    div     ecx     ;do the average (div 5)>>> result in eax

; where should I store the processed pixels?

    inc     edi     ; do the next column
    cmp     edi, im_width   
    jl      proc_pix

    inc             esi     ; do the next row
    mov     edi,1       ; skip the first column 
    cmp     esi, im_height  
    jl      proc_pix

;....................................................................................


new_file: 
    invoke      CreateFile,ADDR filename, GENERIC_WRITE, NULL, NULL,CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0
    mov         hwFile,eax      ; save file handle

; handling of error if invalid file handle
    cmp         eax,INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE
    jne     writef
    invoke      StdOut, addr errMsg ; Display error message
    jmp         QuitNow

writef: invoke      WriteFile, hwFile, pMemory_o, FileSize, ADDR bytesWritten, 0        


QuitNow:
    invoke      GlobalUnlock, pMemory
    invoke      GlobalUnlock, pMemory_o
    invoke      GlobalFree, hMemory
    invoke      CloseHandle, hFile
    invoke      CloseHandle, hwFile
    invoke      ExitProcess, NULL
    end         start

;finish
```

Comment: Wow! Not often to see people work in assembly language... So you know how to read it but not to save it? Looks like you'll have to find out how to do disk space allocation. I'd lke to follow this just for my personal knowledge ;)

Comment: Sounds like you should take a class on data structures and IO in assembly language.

Answer (score 3):

You already have a buffer for the output; you just need to figure out the offset into that buffer to store it, it seems. If the pixel you filtered is (I, J), which you read from `pMemory + im_offset + J * im_width + I`, then you want to write it out to `pMemory_o + im_offset + J * im_width + I`. (As an aside, your code seems to assume 8 bits per pixel; you may want to check that explicitly and quit with an error if it isn't true to avoid unexpected behavior on non-8bpp image files.)

To write the destination pixel correctly, you can do the same row/column multiplication as for reading to get an offset in `eax`, add `im_offset`, and add it to `pMemory_o` (those last two instead of using `ebp` as in the read case).

As well as writing the pixels to the new image, though, you want to copy the header from the source file (so that viewers etc. see it as a bitmap); do a `memcpy` (or appropriate `rep movsb`) from `pMemory` to `pMemory_o`, length `im_offset`, to do that. You also need to copy the first row and column (and, I would expect, the last row and column too, which would have the same problem as the first: you can't get surrounding pixels for some sides) to it. A "dumb" but effective method would just be to copy the entire contents of the old image to the new, header, pixels, and all, and then just change the interior pixels with your filter.

Your code to create and write the output buffer seems correct; presumably it now writes out a zero/random-filled file of the right length.

As an aside, once you get it correct, you can save a lot of work (presumably efficiency is one of the reasons to write in assembly in the first place?) using addition and subtraction instead of multiplying so much: adding `im_width` jumps to the next line, subtracting it to the previous, and so forth (you may have to calculate a stride instead of using `im_width` directly, rounding up to the nearest 32 bits; and if your sample image isn't a multiple of 4 pixels wide, you may see strange results due to not using a correct stride).

Useful references for others following along: the [BITMAPFILEHEADER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183374%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (starting at file offset 0) which contains the signature, file size (your `FileSize`), and image offset (`im_offset`), which is followed by the [BITMAPINFOHEADER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183376%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which has information like the width, height, and bit depth.